# GROUP BY / ORDER BY DESC,(rand)

Tags: mysql, random, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a problem, I hope that somebody can help. In code I have:

```
SELECT * FROM `app_generator_cviky` WHERE `partie` = '$transformnazvu' 
         AND `stupen` <= '$urovenkonkretnihocviku' 
         AND (pohlavi = 'Obě' OR pohlavi = '$pohlavir') 
         GROUP BY zarazeni  ORDER BY poradi DESC, RAND() LIMIT $limitcvikuvpartii
```

But it doesn't random. I always get the first one in group, the rest of this is running OK. What's wrong?

The DB looks like:
[image]

Comment: First step: `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = CONCAT(@@global.sql_mode, ",only_full_group_by");` Second step: Learn how to properly use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ok, Im going to learn it, thank you for advice.